# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level on line 12

Tags: python-3.x

```
fh = open(fname)

lst = list()

for line in fh:
    lst = lst + line.split()

for line in fh:

    for word in line.split() :

        if word not in lst() :

           lst.append(word)   # line 12 ..where is the problem?   

lst.sort()

print lst
```

I want to check if the list has all the fh 's words.if not i have to append the word in list.

Comment: Aren't tabs and spaces mixed in your code?

Comment: It looks like line 12 is only indented 11 spaces when it should be 12.

Comment: you were right but now i take back "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable on line 9" . line 9 is : "if word not in lst() : "

Comment: `if word not in lst()` you should not have the `()` on `lst`

Comment: thank you very much ..i solved it !